# Send image from client to server [ Nodejs / JS / Ejs ]

Tags: node.js, web, multer, alpine-linux

I'm trying to send an image from my web to my server.

Html/Ejs file:

```
<label>
  <input id="boss_img" type="file" accept="image/png, image/svg+xml, image/gif" />
</label>

<div>
  <button onclick="ft_save_image()">Add new boss</button>
</div>
```

Script (Client) file:

```
async function ft_save_image() {
    // Post the image to the server
    const input = document.getElementById("boss_img");
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", input.files[0]);
    console.log(data);

    await fetch("/boss/image/up", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Nodejs (Server):

```
const multer = require('multer');

// Set up storage for uploaded files
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/images/bosses/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
});

// Create middleware for handling file uploads
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Set up a route for handling file uploads
app.post('/boss/image/up', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Received file:', req.file);
  res.send('File uploaded successfully');
});
```

And the error is:

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
App  |     at Multipart._final (/r4i2/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
App  |     at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:696:27)
App  |     at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:725:7)
App  |     at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:735:5)
App  |     at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:633:5)
App  |     at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
App  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

What I'm doing bad? I do the same code in a local server and everything work, but in this case I didn't receive the file.

I already try with event.preventDefault (Not work), also doing the same code in a local environment (Work) but in the VM does not work.

Comment: I believe `file.originalname` returns only file name without extenstion. Therefore, you should specity `file.extname` as well: `cb(null, file.originalname + file.extname)`. That should work.

Comment: @jkalandarov Nop, Internal server error :(